# How to prevent UIImagePickerController from changing orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

So this is my first time I have to work with the IPad camera and I've got some problems with the UIImagePickerController, I can't seem to lock it to portrait mode.

First I subclassed UIImagePickerController and implemented

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

but then I read it's no use as UIImagePickerController shouldn't be subclassed.

Next thing I tried was via the picker overlay, I created a class for it and implemented the same method. Still it doesn't work, the method seems to be called exactly once each time I present the picker with the overlay.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [_imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [_imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [_imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    [_imagePicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    [_imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];  
    [_imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [_imagePicker setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [_imagePicker setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [_imagePicker setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];

    CameraOverlay *_overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc] init];
    [_overlay set_imagePicker:_imagePicker];
    [_imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:_overlay.view];
}

-(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
    [self presentModalViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

I just tried something else, locking the orientation of the presenting view controller, but the UIImagePickerController still rotates in all directions. 
Another thing i noticed is that an orientation change also changes the settings of the UIImagePickerController. I have the camera set to front camera, when I take a picture with it, rotate the IPad and try to take another picture, the camera is set to rear camera. Very strange.

So what did I miss, any suggestions please on how I can lock the camera orientation? :)

Edit: Mixed up UIImagePickerController and UIPickerView, fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always roll your own camera implementation with [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).